# how to change default user agent in python spynner module?

Tags: python, spynner

I get a `syntax error` for the following code:

```
import spynner

browser = spynner.Browser( (['User-Agent', 'foobar')])
```

How can I change the default user agent in the python spynner module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get syntax error because of unmatched brackets.
To change default user agent you can use user_agent argument. Here's an example:
https://github.com/makinacorpus/spynner/blob/c205db628ac41c46f3df07345f547f0fa8ee25ff/examples/proxy.py#L22